# How to delete a node in a circular doubly linked list?

Tags: java, list, null

I'm trying to write a program that will go forwards in a circular doubly linked list a certain amount of times and backwards in the same list a certain amount of times. If both methods end up at the same number then the number is 'worthy' and is removed from the list. If the methods don't end up at the same element on the list then they are unworthy and are removed from the list as well. I've written the method for going forwards and backwards a certain amount of times but I'm having difficulty with removing the elements once they have been deemed worthy or unworthy. This is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class LinkedList {

private Node head;
private Node end;

LinkedList(){
    head = end = null;

}

public void addAtStart(int x){
   
    if (head == null) {  
        Node new_node = new Node(x);  
        new_node.data = x;  
        new_node.next = new_node.prev = new_node;  
        head = new_node;   
    } else if (head != null) {
        Node last = (head).prev;
        Node new_node = new Node(x);  
        new_node.data = x;
        new_node.next = head;
        (head).prev = new_node; 
        new_node.prev = last;
        last.next = new_node;
    }
}

public void printOutput(int N, int k, int m){
    System.out.println("Output" + "\n" + "------" + "\n");
    printCandidates(N,k,m);
 
}

public void printCandidates(int N, int k, int m){
    int unworthy[] = new int[N];
    int worthy[] = new int[N];
    int count = 0;
    int run = 0;
    Node temp = head;
    do {
        if (forwards(k) == backwards(m)){ // puts in worthy list and deletes from linked list
            worthy[count] = forwards(k);
            count += 1;
            System.out.println("hello");
            deleteElement(forwards(k));
        } else if (forwards(k) != backwards(m)){ //put in unworthy list and delete from linked list
            unworthy[run] = forwards(k);
            unworthy[run+1] = backwards(m);
            run += 2;
            System.out.println("goodbye");
            deleteElement(forwards(k));
            deleteElement(backwards(m)); 
        }
    } while (temp != null);
    System.out.println("Removed candidates from being elected");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unworthy));
    System.out.println("Worthy candidates");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(worthy));
}

int forwards(int k){
    int run = 0;
    int x = 0;
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp.next != head){  
        if(run == (k)){
            x = temp.data;
        }
        temp = temp.next;
        run += 1;
    }
    return x;
}

int backwards(int m){
    int run = 0;
    int x = 0;
    Node temp = head;
    Node last = head.prev;  
    temp = last; 
    while (temp.next != head){  
        if(run == (m)){
            x = temp.data;
        } 
        temp = temp.next;
        run += 1;
    } 
    return x;
}

public void deleteElement(int elementToBeDeleted){
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp.next != head){  
        if(temp.data == elementToBeDeleted){
            temp.setNext(temp.next);
        }
        temp = temp.next;
    }  
}
```

This is my driver:

```
public class Program2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++){
        ll.addAtStart(i);
    }
    int N = 10;
    int k = 4;
    int m = 3;
    
    System.out.println("N = " + N + ", " + "k = " + k + ", " + "m = " + m + "\n"); 
    ll.printOutput(N,k,m);
}

}
```

This is my node class:

```
public class Node {
public int data;
public Node next;
public Node prev;


// Constructor to intialize/fill data
public Node(int data){ 
    this.data = data;
}

 // set the address of next node
public void setNext(Node temp) {
    this.next = temp;
}

// get the address of next node
public Node getNext(){
    return this.next;
}


public Node getPrev(){
    return this.prev;
}
public void setPrev(Node temp) {
    this.prev = temp;
}

// to get data of current node
public int getData(){
    return this.data;
}
}
```

EDIT: As part of this exercise I need to write the class myself, therefore why I am implementing my own LinkedList.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own LinkedList?
Use https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Hint: Change the previous and next nodes to link/point to each other, this will effectivly remove the selected node from your linked list.